# troubles ploting double integral matlab

Tags: matlab, symbolic-integration

I want to plot the double integral

[image]

using MATLAB for `s` between `0` and `1`. How can I do this?

I've tried the following code but since this is my first time using MATLAB it didn't worked after two hours:

```
syms r x s
fun=@(r,x)(r^8*sin(x)^8)/((r*sin(x)+1)^7)+....
f=int(fun,x,0,2*pi)
q=int(f,r,0,1)
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: And by "it didn't work" you mean?

Comment: @Benoit_11 I got a lot of errors, which I did not save at work...

Answer (score 0):

You can use function [dblquad](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/dblquad.html) for each value of s on interval.For example(other parts add the feature yourself):

```
Int = zeros(1,101);
F = @(x,r) (r.^8.*(sin(x).^8)./(r.*sin(x)+1).^7);
for s = 1:101
Int(s) = dblquad(F,0,(s-1)*0.01,0,2*pi);
end
plot(0:0.01:1,Int)
```